# How to throw a custom fault code and fault string in a webservice created using IBM Webexperience factory?

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I've created a service provider model in wef 8.0.0.2 and generated the wsdl using the service definition builder. It had a service operation which will authenticate a user, the input is username and password. If the username is invalid i wanted to show the error as a soap fault. So an exception is thrown in the java class which will validate the user name. The soap fault thrown is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>java.rmi.RemoteException: Error in method authenticate.  Error in method authenticateExecute.  Error in method authenticate_al.  Error in method authenticateUser_ljo.authorizeUser.  ||01013||Authentication Failed, Try again !</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">254</ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can see the fault string is showing the trace where the exception is thrown. I only wanted to show the || separated text in the fault string -- **||01013||Authentication Failed, Try again !**
The ljo class to throw the error is also shown

```
public class AuthenticateUser{
public void authorizeUser(WebAppAccess webAppAccess) throws Exception {
        try {
            String username = webAppAccess.getVariables().getString("userNameVar");
            String password = webAppAccess.getVariables().getString("passwordVar");
            if (username.trim().length() == 0 || password.trim().length() == 0) {
                throw new Exception();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Success");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("||01013||Authentication Failed, Try again !");
        }
    }
}
```

How can we set a custom fault code and fault string while throwing an exception.??

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use a customized exception, for example

```
public class AuthException extends Exception {

    public AuthException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

And replace below line in catch block of web service class

throw new AuthException ("||01013||Authentication Failed, Try again !");

Regards

Comment: Yes I created the custom exception. But still it works the same. It wrapping the trace and showing it in the fault string.